# Choosing number of lag AND model form for Augmented Dickey-Fuller test

Tags: time-series, stationarity, information-theory, augmented-dickey-fuller

Before realising an Augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) test, one has to answer 2 questions, how many lags p to include in the model, AND which model to choose among the following:

- No constant, no trend
- Constant, no trend
- Constant, trend

Let us say that I want to study the stationarity of a daily time series (without plotting it or knowing its provenance - I know it can sound stupid, but I would like to do multiple tests and it would thus be far easier not to individually look at the time series).

I have read that information criteria may be used to determine the optimum number of lags - but can it be used to assess at the same time the number of lags AND the correct model? In other words, before running an ADF (without properly knowing the data) should one run the 3 models, with a variant number of lags and look for the one that gives the "best" value for a given information criteria?